# Extract Data off multiple XML row

Tags: php, xml, attributes, xmlnode

I have a really weird XML response and i need to extract it's data. I need to get the data in the "value" attribute but i need to choose them according to their "key" attributes.

This is how it looks like

```
       <phone>
       2125556666
       </phone>
       <State>
       ny
       </State>
       <Response>
           <data key="Supported" value="Yes"/>
           <data key="Host" value="Remote"/>
           <data key="WholeProductList">
               <data key="Product" value="a-z44"/>
               <data key="Product" value="c-k99"/>
               <data key="Product" value="e-b089"/>
               <data key="Product" value="z-p00"/>
               <data key="Product" value="r-333"/>
               <data key="Product" value="t-RS232"/>
               <data key="Product" value="4-lve"/>
               <data key="Product" value="Shutdown"/>
           </data>
       </Response>
```

In PHP i currenty have

```
$xmltmp = new DomDocument;
$xmltmp->loadXml($response);
$phone = $xmlresponse->getElementsByTagName('phone')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$state = $xmlresponse->getElementsByTagName('state')->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $phone;
echo $state;
```

This currently outputs both phone number and state. It works fine.

Now i need to know if the "Supported" key's value is Yes or No, and if it's Yes, i need to get all "Products". I'm kinda stuck because i am having a hard time making the foreach statement and then checking the "key" attribute value.

Thanks!

Comment: Use an XPath query on it; something like setting `Response/data@key` to a variable and checking if that is "Yes".

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Do you think there would be a way to avoid XPath or it would be mandatory? There might be a built in method in the DomDocument class??

Comment: Without XPath you'll probably need to loop all the `<data>` elements - it'll be much neater with XPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML is invalid. An XML document always needs a single document element node.

Example:

```
<root> 
  <phone>2125556666</phone>
  <State>ny</State>
    <Response>
      <data key="Supported" value="Yes"/>
      ...
    </data>
  </Response>
</root>
```

The easiest way to fetch data from a DOM is XPath. In PHP that is provided by the `DOMXPath` class and part of the `ext/dom`. `DOMXPath::evaluate()` allows you to fetch node lists or scalar values from the DOM document.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$phone = $xpath->evaluate('string(/*/phone)');
$state = $xpath->evaluate('string(/*/State)');
var_dump($phone, $state);
```

Output:

```
string(10) "2125556666"
string(2) "ny"
```

An expression like `/*/phone` selects all `phone` element child nodes inside the document element. `string(/*/phone)` casts the first found node into a string and return that. If no node was found, it will return an empty string.

The XPath expression for the supported status is slightly more complex. Conditions for nodes are provided in `[]`. It is possible to compare the result directly in XPath. The return value will be an boolean.

```
$supported = $xpath->evaluate('/*/Response/data[@key="Supported"]/@value = "Yes"');
var_dump($supported);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

If the expression returns a node list you can iterate it with `foreach()`.

```
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate(
  '/*/Response/data[@key="WholeProductList"]/data[@key="Product"]/@value'
);
$products = [];
foreach ($nodes as $attributeNode) {
  $products[] = $attributeNode->value;
}
var_dump($products);
```

Output:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "a-z44"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "c-k99"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "e-b089"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "z-p00"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "r-333"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "t-RS232"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "4-lve"
  [7]=>
  string(8) "Shutdown"
}
```

Comment: Oh wow this is such a complete answer i couldn't not mark it as accepted. Many thanks for the time you took into writting this, i greatly appreciate your efforts into this!!

Comment: Hello!

After a lot of testing, i realised the `$product = [];` does not work. I simply do `$product = array();` and it works perfect. Maybe the `[]` can call an array in another language??

Comment: You have an old php version, current php supports the alternative array syntax.

Comment: Ah - I was assuming it was merely an XML snippet not the whole document; nice answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This won't quite work "as is" since I don't know what the actual structure of the XML document is, but in short you map the XML nodes to XPath like `//root/node/child_node/@attribute` and so on.

It should also have some sanity (not null) type checking in.

```
$xmltmp = new DomDocument;
$xmltmp->loadXml($response);
$xQuery = new DOMXPath($xmltmp);

//not sure what your root node is so the query path is probably wrong
$supported = $xQuery->query('/Response/data[@key="Supported"]/@value')->value;
```

You can also replace:

```
$phone = $xmlresponse->getElementsByTagName('phone')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$state = $xmlresponse->getElementsByTagName('state')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

With something like (again - without the full structure of the XML document the path itself is probably not quite right):

```
$phone = $xQuery->query('/phone')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$state = $xQuery->query('/State')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```